# After migrate to cloud, sql queries are timing out

Tags: php, sql-server, database, cloud

After migrating an application to Azure Cloud, I am getting SQL timeout but only for queries that are pulling large resultset that takes more than 1 sec to retrieve. Small resultsets still work fine.

We connect to a MSSQL database through the local network, nothing has changed there.

Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3
MSSQL 2016 database connected through the network
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

I've tried upgrading the driver to `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll` but that just breaks the connection altogether. The logs are only telling me that it timedout.

Comment: Is your code setting an explicit timeout on the calls into AzureSQL?

Comment: Yes, the code is currently setting a timeout at 90sec to see if we can bring back the results in that time.